# Vertical center in fixed div

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to center the items (`.item`) on the right to the left `.title`
I've tried everything but can't get this to work.
Is it possible that I can use a fixed `em` as padding/ margin?

http://jsfiddle.net/5K9db/6/

Comment: How do you center items on the right and left?  Can you rephrase the question?

Comment: Here an updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/5K9db/5/ - The three words `Item` aren't vertically centered. I want them centered.

Comment: I don't get it. from left to right is called horizontal, from top to bottom is vertical. now you want vertical from right to left?

Comment: It would help if you could show a picture of what you want the result to look like.

Comment: @caramba No, it isn't.

New link: http://jsfiddle.net/5K9db/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look `HERE` and tell us what you want else.